# Responsive Web Design without showing mobile layout when resizing desktop browser?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

http://stackoverflow.com does this, as well as www.ancestry.com. How do these sites keep from showing the mobile layout on a desktop when resizing the browser window if they don't have a separate subdomain? With my understanding, media queries will resize the website according to the viewport, but the both StackOverflow and Ancestry only resize to a certain point - on a phone the layout is completely different. Any help with this? I'd like to know how sites like the examples given achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it's done by forcing a `min-width` on your document, which will incur horizontal scrolling below that size, with:

```
html {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
```

But you should only deliver such CSS if you a have a 100% guarantee that this site will be served only to desktops. That can't be applied to mobile devices. Showing the mobile layout on desktop if a user resizes the window is perfectly normal. It naturally adapts to split screen mode situations.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out there is no 'mobile' specifier. I'm unsure if anyone understands what I'm hoping to achieve here. Ancestry.com (mentioned before) will not show the mobile layout when resizing the window. When I view Ancestry on my phone, however, it is a different look entirely - all while on the same domain - no 'm' subdomain or anything. I'm starting to think it's separate HTML and CSS files entirely, but how? I have heard about Dynamic Serving and I think that's what may be the answer but have yet to find any helpful info on it. Thank you so much for your help thus far

Comment: Yes the Mobile vs. Desktop sites are served dynamically according to the user agent for both sites. You can see that for yourself by changing your user-agent in your desktop browser with a mobile one. You'll see the mobile site at desktop like width. Or use "Request desktop" on a mobile device, and you'll see the 1000ish pixel wide desktop version. But neither of these sites are really using responsive design. They just use the old paradigm of having two different sites served dynamically.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! Now off to learn about Dynamic Serving! Have a good one

Answer (score 0):

I should probably make this a comment but they look at the device width, not the viewport width in their media queries and javascript. (I'm sick and don't feel like writing any more). There are also services available that can help you detect what type of device there is. However, these services can be slow and pricy sometimes. More often not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if your viewer is a mobile or a PC, then load different CCS files.

One way you can detect if there is a mobile is by javascript UserAgent BUT it is not very effective.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // is mobile..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this recently, but there is a 'mobile' device specifier:

```css
@media mobile and (min-width: 400px) {
  .col { width:50% }
}

@media mobile and (max-width: 400px) {
  .col { width:100% }
}
```

That'll work on mobile devices, but not desktop

Comment: Re: "but there is a 'mobile' device specifier:" There is no such a thing in CSS standards specification. @Matt please don't accept that terrible uninformed answer.

Comment: sorry, "handheld" is the type, not "mobile".  Don't know how well supported it is.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html

Comment: `handheld` is not [really well supported if at all](http://alistapart.com/article/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet), by modern mobile devices. At best that's good only for antique *feature* phones. `handheld` is deprecated from [Media Queries Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries-4/#media-types).

Answer (score 0):

I deployed the same scenario on a WordPress site using "mobble pluging" which simply detect the device then generate a HTML version for mobile, tablet or desktop.